# No me cuadran los espacios entre columnas flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Tengo que hacer un main con 1000px de largo y 5 imagenes pero cada imagen ha de tener 300px de largo como maximo, pues hacen 900px, pero no se por qué la 3 imagen se me baja, y tambien no se por que se me hace tanto espacio entre columnas

Necesito que quede asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
*{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: seashell;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    
}

.main-title  {
    width: 100%;
}

.main-galery{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

figure img {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;

}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="main-title">
            <h2>Tea of the month</h2>
            <h4>What's Steeping at the Tea Cozy?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="main-galery">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```css
    *{
    margin:0; 
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: seashell;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    
}

.main-title  {
    width: 100%;
}

.main-galery{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

figure img {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="main-title">
        <h2>Tea of the month</h2>
        <h4>What's Steeping at the Tea Cozy?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="main-galery">
        <figure>
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</main>
```

En el selector principal `*{}` agregué los atributos `margin:0;  padding: 0;` para eliminar por defecto el espaciado automático entre los elementos.

Además en  `figure img {}` modifiqué la propiedad padding dejandola en `padding: 10px;` para que el espaciado sea de 10px uniforme en todos los lados de figure img